# What is the use of the IPv6 scope ID?

Tags: ip, subnet, network, ipv6, ip-address

In the structure `struct sockaddr_in6`, the field `sin6_scope_id` is declared.

What is the use of this member? How can we know from the IPv6 address and the prefix length the scope that it should use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the IPv6 Link-Local addressing, where every interface has the same network (`fe80::/10`), there must be some way to distinguish which specific network is meant when referring to a link-local address. That is what the Scope ID, also called a Zone ID so as not to be confused with the multicast scope flags, is for.

Basically, the scope or zone is the interface in the host for link-local addresses. There are some RFCs around this, e.g. [*RFC 6874, Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874), which explains how to use this for URIs, including web browsers. The `%` character is used to denote the zone at the end of the text address representation:

```
fe80::1:2:3:4%9
```

-or-

```
fe80::1:2:3:4%eth0
```

Unfortunately, not all web browsers support using link-local addressing. There are also some security restrictions, and this should only be used for link-local addressing at this time:

> To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format
> except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local
> addresses under prefix fe80::/10.  At the time of writing, this is the
> only well-defined usage known.

The scope or zone ID is only locally significant:

> An HTTP client, proxy, or other intermediary MUST remove any ZoneID
> attached to an outgoing URI, as it has only local significance at the
> sending host.

How a scope or zone ID is represented is specific to a particular operating system.